# Change Caption of Label

Tags: c++, c, label, atl

I want to change caption (text) of a label in the execution time depending on user input. If user presses a button, my program will execute some stuff and write the output into a label. But I have a problem about this.

First, there's no label in my environment. At least in toolbox. I know, adding from toolbox is not the only way, but I'm a bit scared to touch the old source code and mess things up.

I found a static text element, but I guess because of its a "static" element, I can't see it in resource.h. So, if I use a function like `GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);`, it doesn't work. Because there's no `IDC_STATIC` in my resource.h.

This was the second one.

And, I used `SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC, "text");`, too. However, because of my resource.h doesn't know what `IDC_STATIC` is, I get errors.

Is there a label class/element that is not in toolbox? I guess my `IDC_STATIC` is not in my resource.h because of its static behavior. Or, is there any other way to update the text of a label/static text?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a static control, but give it some identifier other than IDC_STATIC. Then you'll be able to use `GetDlgItemText`, `SetDlgItemText`, etc., with that identifier. Alternatively, you could/can use an EDIT control set to read-only, which is pretty much equivalent to a static control<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Even more than many realize -- for example, to change the background color of a normal edit control, you respond to `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`. To change the background color of a static control *or* read-only edit control, you respond to `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. I'm a bit sleepy, so I found this information after I posted the question. Still, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Change the ID of your static text to something other than `IDC_STATIC`, and change those codes to update it. I wish I tried this 5 mins ago.

Changing the ID of it updates your resource.h and adds your static text in it.

This might help people after me in debugging I guess:

```
TCHAR   *pszBuffer = new TCHAR[255];
pszBuffer = TEXT("dkjhasja");
CWindow wndSys;
wndSys.Attach(GetDlgItem(IDC_BLABLABLA));
wndSys.SetWindowText(pszBuffer);
wndSys.Detach();
```